Как узнать, что окно tkinter закрыли через диспетчер задач?
Я хочу сделать, чтобы сохранение создавалось после выхода из программы, но когда происходит выключение программы через диспетчер задач этого не происходит. Как это, если вообще возможно, сделать?
Я пытался писать код после функции tk.mainloop(), но не сработало. Также я пытался найти решение проблемы, но ничего не нашёл.

А зачем вам вообще убивать процесс своей программы через диспетчер задач?

Ну вдруг друг додумается до такого

После выхода из программы уже никто ничего в этой программе не может сохранить. Потому что уже был выход из программы. Можно выполнить "последнее действие" перед выходом. Вот пример кода для осуществления такого поведения:
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: root_exit())
root.mainloop()

В такой функции Вы как раз и можете осуществлять какие-то свои операции по сохранению чего-то непосредственно перед выходом из программы. Мочить какие-то программы извне и при этом рассчитывать, что они что-то будут для Вас сохранять, мягко говоря, из области фантазий.

Cпасибо, очень помогло.
